# How could I find out the optimal performance of socket.io? In another word, what is the limit of socket.io in bytes/second?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, data-transfer

I am using socket.io listening on my express application. When my server gets an object, the connected socket immediately does socket.emit and send that JSON object to the client.

My question is that the current app is not exactly real time, and I am suspecting that there are way too many objects received by the server and socket cannot send so many large objects over to the client in a timely fashion.

I would like to find out the optimal performance of socket.io, as in I want to program something that sends objects over to the client as fast as possible, and see how fast that is (bytes/second or something similar).

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on so many factors: The server's internet connection, the connection's proximity to the client and the route it requires to get to the client, which of course means the traffic en-route to delivery. The client's connection speed, mode of connection (transport used + security which may require many round trips and handshakes). The bottleneck will probably not be node.js or socket.io, but networking factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `socket.volatile.emit` to drop unnecessary packets automatically - http://socket.io/#how-to-use